# FileSize column empty in Powershell files listing

Tags: powershell

I have windows 10 (Ver 1909). When I issue following CMD, it works fine with proper FILESIZE column.

**Win 10 PS version:**

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      18362  752

PS C:\backup> Get-ChildItem -path c:\temp\*.* -Filter *.ps1 | select name,FileSize,lastwritetime,CreationTime | sort LastWriteTime -descending

Name                                   FileSize LastWriteTime         CreationTime
----                                   -------- -------------         ------------
test.ps1                               1.82 KB  02/06/2019 9:20:47 AM 10/02/2018 8:52:42 AM
test2.ps1                              899  B   02/06/2019 8:17:38 AM 02/06/2019 8:17:37 AM
getlastlogon with server name also.ps1 1.50 KB  02/06/2019 8:13:01 AM 02/06/2019 8:13:01 AM
MyTypes.ps1xml                         1.01 KB  12/11/2018 4:34:10 PM 12/11/2018 4:34:01 PM
Get-LockedOutLocation.ps1              4.70 KB  10/02/2018 9:07:36 AM 10/02/2018 9:07:36 AM
```

But if I Issue this command on windows 2008 server, FILESIZE column is always empty.

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14409  1005

PS C:\Users\barcode> Get-ChildItem -path c:\temp\*.*  | select name,FileSize,lastwritetime,CreationTime | sort LastWrite
Time -descending

Name                                FileSize LastWriteTime         CreationTime
----                                -------- -------------         ------------
PS5-Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3191566-x64.zip          4/21/2020 11:12:22 AM 4/21/2020 11:43:47 AM
barcode_new_Srv.bmp                          6/28/2018 8:40:12 AM  6/28/2018 8:33:25 AM
Install-WMF5.1.ps1                           1/18/2017 3:25:24 PM  4/21/2020 11:43:58 AM
Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3191566-x64.msu              1/13/2017 10:07:44 AM 4/21/2020 11:43:58 AM
```

I tried installing Ps7 also on W2008, but still the FILESIZE column is always empty.

Comment: please add the PoSh version on the failing system - not the ps7, but the other one. there are many differences between ps2 and later versions. i suspect that the underlying dotnet code is the problem.

Comment: Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14409  1005

Answer (score 1):

The property you want is called `Length` (not `FileSize`):

```perl
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\*.* -Filter *.ps1 | select Mame,Length,LastWriteTime,CreationTime | sort LastWriteTime -Descending
```

If you want to see which properties a collection of objects have, pipe to `Get-Member`:

```perl
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\*.* -Filter *.ps1 |Get-Member


   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name                      MemberType     Definition                                                                               
----                      ----------     ----------                                                                               
LinkType                  CodeProperty   System.String LinkType{get=GetLinkType;}                                                 
Mode                      CodeProperty   System.String Mode{get=Mode;}                                                            
Target                    CodeProperty   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Cu...
AppendText                Method         System.IO.StreamWriter AppendText()                                                      
CopyTo                    Method         System.IO.FileInfo CopyTo(string destFileName), System.IO.FileInfo CopyTo(string destF...
Create                    Method         System.IO.FileStream Create()                                                            
CreateObjRef              Method         System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type requestedType)                          
CreateText                Method         System.IO.StreamWriter CreateText()                                                      
Decrypt                   Method         void Decrypt()                                                                           
Delete                    Method         void Delete()                                                                            
Encrypt                   Method         void Encrypt()                                                                           
Equals                    Method         bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                           
GetAccessControl          Method         System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity GetAccessControl(), System.Security.AccessC...
GetHashCode               Method         int GetHashCode()                                                                        
GetLifetimeService        Method         System.Object GetLifetimeService()                                                       
GetObjectData             Method         void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime...
GetType                   Method         type GetType()                                                                           
InitializeLifetimeService Method         System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()                                                
MoveTo                    Method         void MoveTo(string destFileName)                                                         
Open                      Method         System.IO.FileStream Open(System.IO.FileMode mode), System.IO.FileStream Open(System.I...
OpenRead                  Method         System.IO.FileStream OpenRead()                                                          
OpenText                  Method         System.IO.StreamReader OpenText()                                                        
OpenWrite                 Method         System.IO.FileStream OpenWrite()                                                         
Refresh                   Method         void Refresh()                                                                           
Replace                   Method         System.IO.FileInfo Replace(string destinationFileName, string destinationBackupFileNam...
SetAccessControl          Method         void SetAccessControl(System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity fileSecurity)           
ToString                  Method         string ToString()                                                                        
PSChildName               NoteProperty   string PSChildName=f.ps1                                                                 
PSDrive                   NoteProperty   PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C                                                                    
PSIsContainer             NoteProperty   bool PSIsContainer=False                                                                 
PSParentPath              NoteProperty   string PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\mjessen               
PSPath                    NoteProperty   string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\mjessen\f.ps1               
PSProvider                NoteProperty   ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem                             
Attributes                Property       System.IO.FileAttributes Attributes {get;set;}                                           
CreationTime              Property       datetime CreationTime {get;set;}                                                         
CreationTimeUtc           Property       datetime CreationTimeUtc {get;set;}                                                      
Directory                 Property       System.IO.DirectoryInfo Directory {get;}                                                 
DirectoryName             Property       string DirectoryName {get;}                                                              
Exists                    Property       bool Exists {get;}                                                                       
Extension                 Property       string Extension {get;}                                                                  
FullName                  Property       string FullName {get;}                                                                   
IsReadOnly                Property       bool IsReadOnly {get;set;}                                                               
LastAccessTime            Property       datetime LastAccessTime {get;set;}                                                       
LastAccessTimeUtc         Property       datetime LastAccessTimeUtc {get;set;}                                                    
LastWriteTime             Property       datetime LastWriteTime {get;set;}                                                        
LastWriteTimeUtc          Property       datetime LastWriteTimeUtc {get;set;}                                                     
Length                    Property       long Length {get;}                                                                       
Name                      Property       string Name {get;}                                                                       
BaseName                  ScriptProperty System.Object BaseName {get=if ($this.Extension.Length -gt 0){$this.Name.Remove($this....
VersionInfo               ScriptProperty System.Object VersionInfo {get=[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($t...
```